# Creating rugs using ggplot in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a dataframe, having 496 observations of 10 variables which are case,water81, water80,water79,income,education,retire,peop81,cpeop,peop80. Now Iam interested in creating a ggplot (income distribution by retirement) . I also need to create a rugs on the left side of the plot. But when I am trying, rugs are note being created on the left and right side, but are created only on the top and bottom.

```
ggplot(data=dataframe,aes(x=income,fill=retire))+
   geom_histogram()+geom_rug(sides="t",color="red")
```

When sides="b" or "t" rugs are being created. If I use rugs="l" or "r" rugs are not created.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Where would you expect the system to put rug marks on the y-axis of that example plot? And, just as importantly: how would you interpret them? Rug marks are not intended for this kind of data display.

Providing a reproducible example of your code would help, but even without it I can tell that you did not map a `y` variable, which `geom_rug` would require to make `y` axis rug marks.

If you insist on doing this, you would need to generate the y-axis locations manually, and then pass them in to `ggplot`. (Note that I am using pipes from `magrittr` to construct the data)

```
toPlot <-
  mpg %$%
  table(class, cyl) %>%
  as.data.frame()

ggplot(toPlot
       , aes(x = class
             , fill = cyl
             , col = cyl
             , y = Freq)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity"
           , position = "dodge") +
  geom_rug()
```

[image]

Note that I have the bars dodging. Otherwise, your rug marks will either a) not line up with the bars, or b) not be interpretable without the bars.

Here is an example using a numeric variable, using `cut` to break it into bins like a histogram:

```
toPlotNum <-
  mpg %$%
  table(class
        , City = cut(cty,pretty(cty))) %>%
  as.data.frame()

ggplot(toPlotNum
       , aes(x = City
             , fill = class
             , col = class
             , y = Freq)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity"
           , position = "dodge") +
  geom_rug()
```

Or, show densities instead:

```
library(stringr)

ggplot(mpg
       , aes(x = cty
             , col = word(trans, sep = fixed("(")))) +
  geom_density() +
  geom_rug()
```

[image]

Comment: I have a dataset of 10 variables which are listed above in the question. So the retire column consists of Yes or No options and the income column contains the detailed income values in numbers. I need to plot a ggplot2 between income and retire...can you help with this. I also want to know when should I use geom_histogram, geom_point or geom_bar.

Comment: I added a version with a numeric variable (just adding `cut`). What about my answer does *not* show you how to add those rug marks? It may help if you had an example of a plot that looked like what you are trying to create. `geom_histogram` is essentially a wrapper for `geom_bar` that does binning for you. `geom_point` is for a completely different type of data. What is that you are trying to convey in this plot? See my example with `geom_density` as a potential alternative if you are just trying to compare the distributions.